# remove string in json that contains value via jquery or php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

I have json string, which is produced by server.php

```
[{"attr":{"id":"node_7","rel":"default"},"data":"doc.html","state":""},
 {"attr":{"id":"node_8","rel":"folder"},"data":"New node","state":"closed"},
 {"attr":{"id":"node_9","rel":"folder"},"data":"New node","state":""}]
```

How do I remove a full string that contains the value `rel=default`

This is the code I have for server.php.

```
require_once("config.php");
$jstree = new json_tree();




echo $jstree->{$_REQUEST["operation"]}($_REQUEST);
die();
```

Comment: This is the code for server.php

Comment: Where are you processing the JSON?

Answer (score 1):

Using PHP:

```
// convert json string to array
$json = json_decode($json_string);

// filter out items
$json = array_filter($json, function($item)
{
    return $item->attr->rel != "default";
});

// convert back to string
$json_string = json_encode($json);
```

Comment: cant seem to get that to work. This is the code I have in server.php.

Comment: @user1498809:  Saying it just doesn't work isn't very helpful.  Edit your original question to include all the code that's inside `server.php`.

Comment: I dont know what is wrong with stack overflow but I can not add code. Try 4 spaces. Tab does not work. I am using chrome, are there issues with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use data.items.splice(X, Y); to remove an element ;)